# What parameters can be passed to a redirection CloudPage from an inbox notification?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk, inbox

Inbox messages redirecting to CloudPages can be personnalized with system attributes like `subscriberkey` or `_subscriberkey` or `contactid`.

However i'm wondering if these variables are passed to the redirection CloudPage? and in what way they can be retrieved for personnalization inside the Landing Page ?

Comment: Oops sorry I read as Email Inbox :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about "system" personalization strings, but if you send your inbox message from Journey Builder, all the data from your entry source can be used in the CloudPage (source : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_april_2019_mp_jb_entry_source_personalization.htm&type=5). I tested it a few months ago (with a Data Extension entry source) and I confirm that it works.

This does NOT work if you send your inbox message from MobilePush though. In that case no query parameter is passed to the CloudPage, so you get absolutely zero context for personalization in the landing page.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks !